# Sitefinity - updating an existing model

Tags: c#, .net, updates, sitefinity, sitefinity-6.x

I have to work with an exsiting Sitefinity 6.3 project. I need to add some new fields to the models.

Where can I find documentation about how to *updating* a persistent model correctly? I have to update production environment so I would like to be 100% sure about what to do.

Comment: By models to you mean you want to add items to the built in content types? Like news, blogs, etc? Or do you want to know how to add to an MVC widget model?

Comment: For example how can I modify an exising AND not built in type. Let's say there is a "Car" with 5 prooperties and I would like to add 2 more properties (ie. Speed and NumberOfSeats).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that they were built using Module Builder.

Administration > Module Builder > Cars

Here is docs. 
http://docs.sitefinity.com/overview-dynamic-modules-and-the-module-builder

Comment: Thank you. Can you please link me to the corresponding documentation?